# Partially specialize template class for templates with different template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

How can I get a class template to accept another class template that could have one of two different parameter lists? Namely, a non-type parameter or a type and non-type parameter:

```
template <int X>
struct Foo1{};

template <typename T, int X>
struct Foo2{};
```

I want to be able to pass either of these templates to my template (plus future templates that follow in their footsteps). I hope this illustrates what I'm after, although the syntax is all wrong:

```
template <typename T, int X, class>
struct Magic; //Don't accept non template parameters

template <typename T, int X, class <int> class C>
struct Magic<T, X, C> {}; //Template non-type

template <typename T, int X, class <class, int> class C>
struct Magic<T, X, C> {}; //Template type and non-type
```

I can't think of a way to write a specialization for these. If it isn't possible, I can just have `Foo1` and all templates like it have a template type parameter that doesn't do anything (`template <typename, int X> Foo1{};`) and write `Magic` with that in mind, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: [The only](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac1f9446d910331d) solution I can think of

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Brilliant! That definitely answers the question, if you want to make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution you could apply is to introduce wrappers for each distinct class template's declaration, and specialize the magical structure based on what the wrapper wraps. Eventually the only thing you need to know is which wrapper is associated with which class template.

```
template <int X>
struct Foo1{};

template <typename T, int X>
struct Foo2{};

template <template <int> class C> struct W1;

template <template <class, int> class C> struct W2;

template <typename T, int X, class>
struct Magic; //Don't accept non template parameters

template <typename T, int X, template <int> class C>
struct Magic<T, X, W1<C> > {}; //Template non-type

template <typename T, int X, template <class, int> class C>
struct Magic<T, X, W2<C> > {}; //Template type and non-type

int main()
{
    Magic<int, 1, W1<Foo1> > m1;
    Magic<int, 2, W2<Foo2> > m2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f17844a7bac054)